# Way to manage resources like JMX does in Netty

Tags: jmx, netty

Does Netty provide any mechanism to monitor resources like JMX does?

I did find an article on http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Netty4andJMXIntegration [Netty4 and JMX Integration] but it is only a proposal.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no JMX support in netty yet.